# Why I don't see all the spring prometheus metrics with WebClient

Tags: java, spring, prometheus, webclient, metrics

when I try to dynamically create a WebClient from a configuration file (application.properties) some prometheus metrics disappear, such as the jvm metrics

I use spring boot 2.7.0, jdk 17.

1/ First I load the configurations about the actuator's metrics
To do this, I have a spring.factories that contains

```
org.springframework.boot.env.EnvironmentPostProcessor=re.test.pos.api.actuator.LoadActuatorDefaultProperties
```

In the class LoadActuatorDefaultProperties, I load in Environment the contains of the acutator-default.properties which contains for example :

```
    management.server.port=4242
    management.endpoint.health.show-details=always
    management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*

    management.endpoints.jmx.exposure.exclude=*
    spring.jmx.enabled=true

    management.endpoint.health.probes.enabled=true
```

2/ In a second time, I use a "re.test.pos.api.consumer.WebClientInstanceBuilderAutoConfiguration" in order to create a WebClientInstanceBuilder with the configuration containing in the application.properties which contains for example :

```
    xoapi.consumer.services.accountManagement.url=https://test.api:8443/test
    xoapi.consumer.services.accountManagement.headers[Content-Type]=application/json
    xoapi.consumer.services.accountManagement.headers[Accept-Language]=fr
```

My goal is to retrieve parameters starting with xoapi.consumer and push them into the ConsumerProperties class.
After that, WebClientInstanceBuilderAutoConfiguration class load ConsumerProperties and instantiate a WebClientInstanceBuilder and a WebClient.Builder with this kind of command :

```
    return serviceBuilder.baseUrl(service.getUrl()).defaultHeaders(httpHeaders -> {
            service.getHeaders().forEach(httpHeaders::add);
        }).codecs( codecs -> {
            codecs.defaultCodecs().maxInMemorySize(this.maxInMemorySize.intValue());
        });
```

3/ After that, when I try the URL http://localhost:4242/actuator/prometheus in my browser I see the next metrics :

```
executor_active_threads{name="applicationTaskExecutor",} 0.0
executor_pool_size_threads{name="applicationTaskExecutor",} 0.0
tomcat_sessions_alive_max_seconds 0.0
tomcat_sessions_expired_sessions_total 0.0
tomcat_sessions_created_sessions_total 0.0
executor_queued_tasks{name="applicationTaskExecutor",} 0.0
executor_queue_remaining_tasks{name="applicationTaskExecutor",} 2.147483647E9
application_started_time_seconds{main_application_class="re.test.pos.api.PointsOfSaleApiApplication",} 9.399
tomcat_sessions_rejected_sessions_total 0.0
executor_completed_tasks_total{name="applicationTaskExecutor",} 0.0
tomcat_sessions_active_max_sessions 0.0
executor_pool_core_threads{name="applicationTaskExecutor",} 8.0
executor_pool_max_threads{name="applicationTaskExecutor",} 2.147483647E9
application_ready_time_seconds{main_application_class="re.test.pos.api.PointsOfSaleApiApplication",} 9.433
tomcat_sessions_active_current_sessions 0.0
```

4/ In the application.properties, if I put in comment :

```
#xoapi.consumer.services.accountManagement.url=https://test.api:8443/test
#xoapi.consumer.services.accountManagement.headers[Content-Type]=application/json
#xoapi.consumer.services.accountManagement.headers[Accept-Language]=fr
```

As there are no longer any associated configurations for WebClient creation, the WebClientInstanceBuilderAutoConfiguration class no longer attempts to instantiate a WebClient.

In this case, if I try the URL http://localhost:4242/actuator/prometheus in my browser I see a lot of metrics, more than in the above example. For example I see the jvm metrics :

```
process_cpu_usage 0.1100376909902195
executor_pool_max_threads{name="applicationTaskExecutor",} 2.147483647E9
jvm_threads_live_threads 37.0
tomcat_sessions_rejected_sessions_total 0.0
jvm_threads_states_threads{state="runnable",} 10.0
jvm_threads_states_threads{state="blocked",} 0.0
jvm_threads_states_threads{state="waiting",} 22.0
jvm_threads_states_threads{state="timed-waiting",} 5.0
jvm_threads_states_threads{state="new",} 0.0
jvm_threads_states_threads{state="terminated",} 0.0
jvm_gc_memory_promoted_bytes_total 6495232.0
tomcat_sessions_alive_max_seconds 0.0
jvm_gc_memory_allocated_bytes_total 7.1303168E7
executor_pool_size_threads{name="applicationTaskExecutor",} 0.0
....
```

5/ Questions :

Why I don't see all the metrics if I create a WebClient ?

6/ Here a zip file with the code
[text](https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer/files/12790078/pointsofsalemetricsnotcomplete-api.zip)

Dezip the archive and run mvn clean install
After thaht => run java -jar target\pos-api-1.0.1.jar

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how `WebClient` is instantiated but, if you rely on the `WebClient.Builder` bean provided by [`WebClientAutoConfiguration`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/main/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/reactive/function/client/WebClientAutoConfiguration.java#L53), metrics should work out of the box.

Internally, in spring boot 2.7.x, metrics are initialized using [`MetricsWebClientCustomizer`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/2.7.x/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-actuator/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/actuate/metrics/web/reactive/client/MetricsWebClientCustomizer.java#L53) attaching filter functions (`MetricsWebClientFilterFunction`) to the `WebClient.Builder`.

You can "mirror" this logic and add corresponding filters explicitly to your client, but using `WebClient.Builder` is a recommended approach.

One possible solution is to create factory and use it to instantiate `WebClient`

```
@Component
public class WebClientFactory {
    private final WebClient.Builder webClientBuilder;

    public WebClientFactory(WebClient.Builder webClientBuilder) {
        this.webClientBuilder = webClientBuilder;
    }

    public WebClient get(String baseUrl) {
        // we need to clone builder otherwise filters will be accumulated from different clients
        return webClientBuilder.clone()
                .baseUrl(baseUrl)
                .build();
    }
}
```

The advantage of this approach is that you can add more cross-cutting logic (common filters, timeout settings, ...) into the factory that all your clients "inherit" the same settings.

In spring boot 3.x internals of metrics initialization were reworked and [`ObservationWebClientCustomizer`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/3.0.x/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-actuator/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/actuate/metrics/web/reactive/client/ObservationWebClientCustomizer.java) is using to initialize metrics, but if you rely `WebClient.Builder` no changes will be required on app side.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer

This is what I've done in the WebClientInstanceBuilder class, which implements the BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor interface.

In the postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry method I build the WebClient and put it in the registry.

One thing I've noticed: as soon as I remove the BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor implements, I can see all the metrics.

Maybe this is the problem ?